# itextsharp Callback pdf document while click on print button on generated pdf

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, itext, razorengine

[image]

Is there any possibility or any builtin function on iTextsharp that while click on print button on pdf generated file the function call from server side? Basically I want to change the status for this file that it is printed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to add a comment but:

basically printing is organized from your pdf-browser. So If you hit the print button, itextsharp is not able to detect. A possible Workaround is to trigger the printing process with a button from your document. Combined with a JavaScript you could write a global variable that marked the printing process for this document.

If you want to keep your document sate, you have to safe it after executing the js-script.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any possibility to trigger any function from jquery while click on Print button from pdf file? What jquery functionality I have to write on my page? From this function I want to make a ajax call on server side and change the it's status accordingly. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Since the screenshot you attached is the pdf viewer of the browser, which runs on the client, you have no interaction any more with the server. So, at this point, you can't control what's happening with the pdf. What you can do, it to tell the browser not to `open` the pdf file, but to `print` it.
Here are some tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+print+directly+to+default+printer

Comment: Marvin Klar, I didn't want to restrict the open functionality. I want to open it on browser and then print it. Is there any possibility to trigger any function from jquery while click on Print button from pdf file?